# cannot initilize a list using getx flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I have a list and I want to initilize it by getting the data from the database. and this error message appears

[Get] the improper use of a GetX has been detected.
You should only use GetX or Obx for the specific widget that will be updated.
If you are seeing this error, you probably did not insert any observable variables into GetX/Obx
or insert them outside the scope that GetX considers suitable for an update
(example: GetX => HeavyWidget => variableObservable).
If you need to update a parent widget and a child widget, wrap each one in an Obx/GetX.

```
class PasswordController extends GetxController {
   final passwordsList = <Password>[].obs;

   final db = Dao.instance;

Future<void> initilizePasswordsList() async {
   final passwords = await db.getAllPasswords();
   passwordsList.addAll([...passwords]);
   return;
}
}
```

```
    Future<void> main() async {
    final passwordController = Get.put(PasswordController());
    await passwordController.initilizePasswordsList();

    runApp(const MyApp());
    }
```

```
  const PasswordsList({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetX<PasswordController>(
      builder: (controller) {
        return ListView(
          children: controller.passwordsList
              .map((e) => Obx(
                    () => PasswordTile(
                      password: e.password,                     
                      websiteName: e.websiteName,
                    ),
                  ))
              .toList(),
        );
      },
    );
}
}
```

Comment: that error appear because inside obx must has obs variable, e.password and e.websiteName is not obs variable. you must has one obs variable inside obx

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `Obx` inside the `ListView` as `e` is not observable, `passwordList` is. And you are already observing it with `GetX`. Therefore your `ListView` should look like:

```
ListView(
      children: controller.passwordsList
          .map((e) => PasswordTile(
                  password: e.password,                     
                  websiteName: e.websiteName,
                ),
              )
          .toList(),
    );
```